# How do I increase workspace width in r

Tags: r

I am running R from linux. 
When I try to print out a table the columns wrap around instead of printing across my screen. How do I increase the workspace width?

Solved :

options(width = 200)

Answer (score 1):

Set the global [`width` option](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/options), for example:

```
options(width = 200)
```